# 2001 VW TDI New Beetle after refrigerant added, car has an on and off pulsing vibration. the ac is on and off as well and the acceleration falters

Tags: vw, ac, beetle

After my husband added coolant to my VW AC, that same night a rumbling vibration started (sounds like under the hood)  - on/off on/off.  It stays on when idle. (Manual transmission) Now the AC is coming on and off - cold, then barely cool - and with less power.  Also, when I accelerate it falters, like I'm stepping on and off the gas pedal

Answer (score 1):

Compressor cycling is caused mostly by low Freon levels or over charged system. Likely possibility is it has been over charged. Recommend taking it to an A/C Certified shop and having the system evacuated, vacuumed and charged to the correct amount.